# Имеется ли возможность получить реальный объект, а не Proxy класс Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, lazyloading, proxy-class

**Предисловие:**

1. Пишется сложный логгер на основе рефлексии, Doctrine UnitOfWork и метаданных.
2. Возможности отрефакторить сущности и добавить аннотацию `fetch="EAGER"` **нет** (получим не гибкую реализацию).
3. Установлена дефолтная конфигурация для EntityManager, которая автоматически генерирует Proxy-классы для связей (отказать от этой возможности тоже **не можем**).
4. Вариант с `$this-em->detach($entity)` - это не вариант, т.к. уходим из под Doctrine, в данном случае, в рамках логгера, недостижимая роскошь (так же, принесет больше проблем, чем пользы).

**Вопрос:**
Из предисловия уже наверно понятно, что необходимо получить реальный объект, а не Proxy-класс. Имеется ли такая возможность (если нет, хотелось бы услышать почему, т.к. в каких-то частных случаях, это крайне необходимо)?

**Дополнение:** смотрел переписку разработчиков Doctrine, много гуглил, по всей видимости, складывается ощущение, что такой возможности нет, однако, имеется догма с утверждением, что это все таки реализуемо.

**Код и результат попыток:**

```
$userRepo     = $this-em->getRepository(User::class);
$userRoleRepo = $this->em->getRepository(UserRole::class);

$user     = $userRepo->find(1);
$userRole = $userRoleRepo->find(1); // принадлежит $user

var_dump(get_class($user->getUserRole())); // соответственно string(47) "Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\UserRole"
var_dump(get_class($userRole)); // аналогично предыдущему дампу, это понятно, т.к. ссылаемся на тот же, уже полученный Proxy-класс (так работает Doctrine, только один инстанс одного и того же наблюдаемого объекта).

// попытки
$userRole->getId(); // это бы помогло, если бы была указана аннотация
var_dump(get_class($userRole)); // string(47) "Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\UserRole"

$userRole->setName('changedName'); // удивительно, но мы работаем все с тем же Proxy
var_dump(get_class($userRole)); // string(47) "Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\UserRole"

$userRole->__load(); // вариант из сети
var_dump(get_class($userRole)); // string(47) "Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\UserRole"

// этот вариант фигурирует везде (в сети), как рабочий, однако - нет
$proxyClassName   = get_class($userRole);
$realClassName    = $this-em->getClassMetadata($proxyClassName)->rootEntityName;
$isOriginUserRole = $this->em->find($realClassName, $userRole->getId());
var_dump(get_class($userRole)); // string(47) "Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\UserRole"

$uR = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('ur')
        ->from($realClassName, 'ur')
        ->where('ur.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', 1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_OBJECT);
var_dump(get_class($uR)); // string(47) "Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\UserRole"
```

**Желаемый результат:**

```
$userRepo     = $this-em->getRepository(User::class);
$userRoleRepo = $this->em->getRepository(UserRole::class);

$user     = $userRepo->find(1);
$userRole = $userRoleRepo->find(1);

// некий код, который позволит получить реальный инстанс UserRole

var_dump(get_class($userRole)); // "string(19) App\Entity\UserRole"
var_dump(get_class($user->getUserRole())); // "string(19) App\Entity\UserRole"
```

**Предметная область проблемы (извиняюсь за отход от темы вопроса):**

```
$realObjectNotProxy     = $anyRepo->find(1);
$originalDataOfNotProxy = $this->em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($realObjectNotProxy);
var_dump(array_keys($originalDataOfNotProxy)); // получаем непустой массив свойств объекта $realObjectNotProxy

// тут должно быть получение сущности, которая ссылается на $proxyObject, чтобы как раз он был вгружен как Proxy
$proxyObject         = $anyRepoProxy->find(1);
$originalDataOfProxy = $this-em->>getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($proxyObject)
var_dump(array_keys($originalDataOfProxy)); // получаем пустой массив :(
```

**P.S.** Код переписан с реального, сущности User и UserRole взяты из головы, чтобы не нагружать вопрос бизнесом.

Answer (score 0):

Прокси-объекты используются для механизма lazy при запросе данных. по умолчанию lazy, запрос в БД пойдет как только вы вызовете связанную сущность

Варианта 2:

1. вы можете явно в маппинге указать, например

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserRole", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
   public ArrayCollection $roles;

Теперь все запросы getUserRoles() будут доставать нормальный объект, предварительно в запросе из репозитория их получая

2. Вы можете написать метод в репозитории, где приджойните связанные сущности и получите также объекты с связанными данными без допзапроса

Обойти иначе не получится, тк для составления запроса данных ORM руководствуется настройками жадности (eager, lazy, extra_lazy) или квери-билдером, который направляет какие данные нужно выбирать  — джойн явно указывает, что надо в запросе эти данные получить, а тк получит их — значит загидрирует уже реальный объект, а не его проксюху

Просто представьте, что вы отключили проксирование...  lazy по умолчанию в маппинге, то есть  ORM не добавит получение их в запрос, на основе каких данных реальный объект гидрировать? :)